# Replace specific character with regex or other possible method

Tags: java, regex

Hi I want to replace all the text with pattern `<%= anything %>` become
`<%= someFunction(anything) %>`. I want to keep the anything part in new string.

Example:

```
<%= user %>
<%= encode(user) %>

OR

<%=user%>
<%=encode(user)%>
```

Is there possible to to that with REGEX or other method?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with a *regular expression*. The pattern `\\s*` matches optional whitespace and `\\S+` matches one (or more) non-whitespace characters. You can combine that with `String.format`. Something like,

```
String str = "<%= user %>"; // <-- the input String
String function = "encode"; // <-- the function to add
// Create an output pattern using $1; the first match to `()` in replaceAll.
String replacement = String.format("<%%= %s($1) %%>", function);
str = str.replaceAll("<%=\\s*(\\S+)\\s*%>", replacement);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
<%= encode(user) %>
```

Comment: @Kim Try my code. Replace "user" with "anything" like `String str = "<%= anything %>";` and you'll get `<%= encode(anything) %>`; similarly, change `function` like `String function = "doSomethingElse";` and get `<%= doSomethingElse(anything) %>`.

Comment: Hi elliot, I got this error when I try.
An error occurred at line: 24 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote.

Line 24 is: String replacement = String.format("<%%= %s($1) %%>", function);

Comment: @Kim You added a quote to my code, it's `String.format("<%%= %s($1) %%>", function);`

Comment: Still got the same error, I already copy and paste your string.format code.

Btw this is my code:
http://pastebin.com/aawWh66v

Comment: Hi elliot the code works, when I used it with Java console @_@
Thanks :D

But the code got some error when the pattern like this:
<option value="<%=kep(1,i)%>"><%=kep(1,i)%></option>

Answer (score 0):

Regex should work, something like this

```
String res = "xxx  <%= anything %> xxx".replaceAll("<%= (.*) %>", "<%= func($1) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
str.replaceAll("\\<%= (.*) %\\>","<%= blah($1) %=>");
```

The first part is the pattern (what you want to find), and the second part is the replacement (what you want it to look like).

Refer to:
http://fiddle.re/u374q6

I suggest reading more about regex [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and playing around on that first link.

Comment: There is no method `Replace` with a capital in String. There is a method `replace` but that method does *not* work with regular expressions.

Comment: whoops sorry, meant to be replaceAll(). Too much c#.